# How to calculate average date occurrence frequency in SQL

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, datetime, frequency

I'm trying to produce a query on the following table (relevant portion only):

```
Create Table [Order] (
  OrderID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
  CreationDate datetime NOT NULL,
  CustomerID int NOT NULL
)
```

I would like to see a list of CustomerIDs with each customer's average number of days between orders. I'm curious if this can be done with a pure set based solution or if a cursor/temp table solution is necessary.

Comment: Too bad SQL Server doesn't support LEAD or LAG... :/

Comment: If a customer makes 4 orders on 1 day and then one more 5 days later what is their average? Is it `(0 + 0 + 0 + 5)/4 = 1.25` ?

Comment: If we allow fractional date differences I think we'll be ok since realistically there will always be some time difference (minutes) between customer orders.

Comment: SQL Server 2012 supports LEAD and LAG.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
;WITH base AS
     ( 
     SELECT  CustomerID,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (partition BY CustomerID ORDER BY CreationDate, OrderID) AS rn
     FROM     [Order]
     )
SELECT   b1.CustomerID,
         AVG(DATEDIFF(DAY,b1.CreationDate, b2.CreationDate) )
FROM     base b1
         JOIN base b2
         ON       b1.CustomerID=b2.CustomerID
         AND      b2.rn        =b1.rn+1
GROUP BY b1.CustomerID
```